# Crawler in python

Tags: python

I have a website (my college website) for which each student has a username/password to login into his account. The website consists of many files uploaded in different formats. I want to programmatically enter my credentials and login to my account and download all files that have been uploaded in the site.

Is there any python module that would authenticate html form and provide access to the pages and then allow downloading files present in those pages?

Comment: Yes.  There is.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: All that i want to do is download files that are present in a website that can be accessed only by providing credentials.

Comment: ok..is there any python module that would authenticate html form and provide access to the pages and then allow downloading files present in those pages?

Comment: "Is there any python module...?"  Yes.  The answer is almost always "Yes".  You should -- perhaps -- ask your **real** question.  Merely testing for existence isn't very informative.  Perhaps you'd like to know **which** module? Or perhaps you'd like to search Stack Overflow for existing questions that are just like your question.  For example, all of these may already answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+crawler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at http://scrapy.org. It's python based crawler/scraper that you can customize to perform any workflow you want. Here's an example of how user authentication is handled: http://doc.scrapy.org/topics/request-response.html?highlight=username#request-usage-examples